# Quartz.net, c# ASP.Net MVC3

Tags: c#-4.0, quartz.net

someone know a tutorial to get started Quartz.net

thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0):

It's incredible that people would rather spend time writing a question on SO than typing in Google search box.

http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/index.html

Comment: That tutorial appears to be for Quartz.net 1.x, rather than 2.x, so maybe it wasn't such a daft question :P

Comment: @Cocowalla - The question is about version 1, not version 2 (see tags used).

Comment: I guess it's a bit ambiguous. The date the question was asked, and the [c#-4.0] tag, suggests he means version 2, whereas the [quartz.net] tag could mean v1 or v2 (I just found there is a [quartz.net-2.0], but still :)